# Switch from maven to gradle - android studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle

I cloned a project on github that is using Maven as a builder but now I need to use Gradle. Im pretty new to android so I could appreciates a little help with this.

What I have found online is either old or non-helpful information

So my question is, how do i switch from Maven to Gradle inside Android Studio?

Comment: Problem is: How.. How do i switch these builders?

Comment: Did you try to search for it? there are many tutorials available for it on the internet.

Comment: Realy? Yes i did search for it and only found outdated or un-useless informations. I see a lot of toturiols about starting project with gradle/maven but not changing from maven to gradle so if you see something then please do share. I will keep trying.

Comment: You can start from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html . If it's an Eclipse project, just import it to Android Studio, and rest will be done.